# How to get the required values from the below mentioned xml file?

Tags: python-3.x, xml

**1)  i want to read below mentioned XML file and access the values, i already tried in many ways but not able to access, for example i want 'NightRaidPerformanceCPUScore' value and that is from which passIndex.**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<benchmark>
    <results>
        <result>
            <name />
            <description />
            <passIndex>-1</passIndex>
            <sourceId>C:\Users\dgadhipx\Documents\3DMark\3dmark-autosave-20200401155825.3dmark-result</sourceId>
            <NightRaidPerformance3DMarkScore>2066</NightRaidPerformance3DMarkScore>
            <NightRaidPerformanceCPUScore>1454</NightRaidPerformanceCPUScore>
            <NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsScore>2233</NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsScore>
            <benchmarkRunId>8045dec5-e97c-452b-abeb-54af187fd50a</benchmarkRunId>
        </result>
        <result>
            <name />
            <description />
            <passIndex>0</passIndex>
            <sourceId>C:\Users\dgadhipx\Documents\3DMark\3dmark-autosave-20200401155825.3dmark-result</sourceId>
            <NightRaidPerformanceCPUScoreForPass>1454</NightRaidPerformanceCPUScoreForPass>
            <NightRaidPerformance3DMarkScoreForPass>2066</NightRaidPerformance3DMarkScoreForPass>
            <NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsScoreForPass>2233</NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsScoreForPass>
            <NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsTest1>9.57</NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsTest1>
            <NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsTest2>12.18</NightRaidPerformanceGraphicsTest2>
            <NightRaidCpuP>395.2</NightRaidCpuP>
            <benchmarkRunId>8045dec5-e97c-452b-abeb-54af187fd50a</benchmarkRunId>
        </result>
    </results>
</benchmark>
```

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup module and then find all elements to you want by tags find_all(and tag name) that will return you all matches tags.

Comment: `i already tried in many ways but not able to access` you should show what you have tried. Otherwise people will assume you just want free code

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup as fellow:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
     content = f.read()
xml = BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')
elements = xml.find_all("NightRaidPerformanceCPUScore")
for i in elements:
    print(i.text)
```

That will print you the values of all "NightRaidPerformanceCPUScore" tags.

Comment: You welcome, can you please vote and mark the question as answered.

Comment: Good luck mate!